# Помогите исправить ошибку: AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'lineEdit"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyowm

Помогите пожалуйста! Никак не могу исправить.

Ошибка в строке `place = self.lineEdit.text()`

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import WA31
import pyowm

class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, WA31.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(get_weather)

def get_weather(self):
    owm = pyowm.OWM('7c6d5748acf9ac9cc2f17c86e2354ee6')
    place = self.lineEdit.text()
    observation = owm.weather_at_place(place)
    w = observation.get_weather()

    temp = w.get_temperature('celsius')["temp"]

    self.textBrowser.setText(f'Тумпература: { temp }')
 


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
window = ExampleApp()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: опубликуйте модуль `WA31.py`

Comment: Функция `get_weather(self)` не должна быть в классе?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import WA31
import pyowm

class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, WA31.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.get_weather)  # + self.

    # ---->
    def get_weather(self):
        owm = pyowm.OWM('7c6d5748acf9ac9cc2f17c86e2354ee6')
        place = self.lineEdit.text()
        observation = owm.weather_at_place(place)
        w = observation.get_weather()

        temp = w.get_temperature('celsius')["temp"]

        self.textBrowser.setText(f'Тумпература: { temp }')
 

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
window = ExampleApp()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!